# Windows Server DHCP server reservation list

Tags: dhcp, windows-command-prompt

In Windows Server acting as a DHCP server, how can I get a list of the DHCP reservations from the CMD? I need to know

- the MAC address and
- the IP address reserved to that MAC address inside the DHCP server.

Right now I have to right click every single item and go to Properties.

Comment: I removed the Windows 2008 Server mentioned, as it's EoL, although you mentioned "or later". As the same still applies to Windows Server 2012-2019, this question should not be closed as off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Since Windows Server 2003 there has been `netsh dhcp server`. You need a command prompt with administrative privileges to use it. E.g. for the list of the DHCP reservations:

```
netsh dhcp server scope 192.0.2.0 show reservedip
```

Or from another machine:

```
netsh dhcp server \\SERVERNAME scope 192.0.2.0 show reservedip
netsh dhcp server <ServerIP> scope 192.0.2.0 show reservedip
```

If you don't know the scope address, you can list all scopes on the server with:

```
netsh dhcp server show scope
```

Or you could even export the whole server configuration into a file (only on the local server):

```
netsh dhcp server export c:\temp\dhcpdb
```

The `netsh` has its documentation baked in: you can get a list of commands currently available by giving an incomplete command. You could start with:

```
C:\Windows\system32>netsh dhcp server
list                          - Lists all the commands available.
dump                          - Dumps configuration to a text file.
help                          - Displays help.
. . .
```

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell module [DhcpServer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dhcpserver/?view=win10-ps) has [`Get-DhcpServerv4Reservation`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dhcpserver/get-dhcpserverv4reservation?view=win10-ps):

```
Get-DhcpServerv4Reservation -ComputerName "dhcpserver.contoso.com" -ScopeId 10.10.10.0
```

Comment: with the cmd. i can't load powershell modules.

Answer (score 0):

`arp -a`
Shows list of current reservations on your network. Addresses with type=dynamic are reserved addresses